# What is the proper way to use bit array in Rust?

Tags: rust, bitarray

I need a class with functionality equal to `vector<bool>` in C++. [The Rust documentation tells about `BitVec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html), but `use std::collections::BitVec` causes *Unresolved import* error during compiling. According to [a pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27998), `BitVec` has been removed. Is there any adequate replacement for it?

Comment: https://crates.io/search?q=BitVec   ?

Comment: "*Rust documentation tells about BitVec*" -> could you link to where the documentation says that? Maybe it's indeed a documentation bug.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html

Comment: 1.2.0... _Years_ old. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn, so the onliest way is to use it via Cargo.toml?

Comment: @Vercetti You can use crates without Cargo, FWIW. You're just advised not to.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There does not exist a dedicated bit-vector in the standard library and `Vec<bool>` is not specialized like C++'s `vector<bool>`. Rust advocates the use of external crates instead of building a huge standard library. The de-facto crate for this use case is [`bit-vec`](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec).

You appear to have found a link to an old standard library documentation: `https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html`. Note the `1.2.0` in the url! The current version of Rust is 1.25 (as of April 2018), which means that `1.2` is already more than two years old. Apart from that, `BitVec` is marked as unstable in the 1.2 docs; it was removed later.

Comment: *`Vec<bool>` is not specialized like C++'s `vector<bool>`* — thankfully. That was not a great decision: let's have a `vector` that *behaves differently*.

Comment: Just a heads up: this crate "is in maintenance mode, due to insufficient maintainer resources"

Comment: There's also the confusingly named `bitvec` crate which I've found to be somewhat more featureful. https://docs.rs/bitvec

Comment: IMHO, to prefer random crates instead of a comprehensive (and curated) standard library is wasting anyones time. Moving targets. Crates falling in and out of favor... In Common Lisp I have bit-vector right out of the box and I do not need to go on a scavenger hunt...

Comment: @AleksandarDimitrov I tried to use that bitvec crate and it has horrible usability. I ended up rolling my own for my specific use case. (`arr.get(i).as_deref() == Some(&true)`... really=?! lol).