# How to convert a bool array into a byte array

Tags: rust

How do I convert a bool array into a byte array?

I would like the resulting vector to have 1/8th the length of the input vector.

Like this

```rust
let a = [false; 160];
let b: [u8; 20] = ???
```

I guess I can make a for-loop and do some arithmetic, but I wonder if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Could you clarify your question. What is the result at `???`

Comment: @bill.gates That's the question, what does he have to write there in order to convert `a` to `b`

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717192/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-bit-array-in-rust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the crate-based solutions, the "hand-rolled" version isn't too difficult to implement, and avoids the allocations:

```rust
    let mut b = [0u8;20];
    for (idx, bit) in a.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let byte = idx / 8;
        let shift = 7 - idx % 8;
        b[byte] |= (bit as u8) << shift;
    }
```

The issue making this generic is that the current const generics don't support arithmetics on constants.

In nightly with `generic_const_expr`, it's possible for the thing to work on arbitrary input sizes (this incomplete implementation will panic on incomplete trailing bytes):

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

fn to_bits<const N: usize>(bools: [bool;N]) -> [u8;N/8] {
    let mut out = [0;N/8];
    for (idx, bit) in bools.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let byte = idx / 8;
        let shift = 7 - idx % 8;
        out[byte] |= (bit as u8) << shift;
    }
    out
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = [false; 160];
    a[42] = true;
    let b = to_bits(a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

though I think `bitvec` also has a `BitArray` type which might allow doing this without allocations as well.

Comment: You went with the opposite bit-endianness that I did. In your first piece of code, `let shift = 7 - idx % 8;` can be replaced with `let shift = idx % 8;` to flip the bit-endianness.

Comment: Might break if `N % 8 != 0`, e.g. `[bool;15]`  becomes `[u8; 1]` which is definitely wrong. maybe `[0; (N+7)/8]`?

Comment: @Finomnis it doesn't become anything, it currently panics, as noted in the answer. Feel free to fix it (and remove the note) if you feel that's important.

Comment: Not really. One can see the concept.

Answer (score 2):

This works and doesn't require a new dependency.

```rust
    let mut b = [0u8;20];
    for i in 0..160 {
        b[i / 8] |= u8::from(a[i]) << (i % 8);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that with just the built-in `std` library.

With the excellent [bit-vec](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec) crate, though:

```rust
use bit_vec::BitVec;

fn main() {
    let mut a = [false; 160];
    a[42] = true;

    let bitvec: BitVec = a.into_iter().collect();

    let b: [u8; 20] = bitvec.to_bytes().try_into().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

You can put it inside a generic function, but that requires nightly and unstable features:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

use bit_vec::BitVec;

fn convert_vector<const N: usize>(bits: [bool; N]) -> [u8; N / 8] {
    let bitvec: BitVec = bits.into_iter().collect();
    bitvec.to_bytes().try_into().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = [false; 160];
    a[42] = true;

    println!("{:?}", convert_vector(a));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`bitvec` crate](https://crates.io/crates/bitvec), something like this should come close:

```
use bitvec::vec::BitVec;

let a = [false; 160];
let b = [0; 20]
b[..].copy_from_slice (a.iter().collect::<BitVec>().as_raw_slice());
```